# Commet Form Error: You are not allowed to post comments

Tags: comments, comment-form

Thanks For Taking The Time To Read!

This has me a bit stumped: Error generates upon form submit.

- Live Site
- Checked several times for allowing comments in both System Settings & Channel
- First Site with EE 3  (Core)
- Used different emails/comment tests

Page Link: http://www.stevenseppinni.com/index.php/site/article_detail_video/this-is-a-video-example

```
<section id="comments">
          <h6 class="section-title">3 Comments</h6>
          <p>Comments are optional and I am editable! Whoop!</p>
          <ol class="comments-list">
{exp:comment:entries sort="desc" orderby="date" limit="20" dynamic="no"}
            <li class="comment">
              <article> {if avatar} <img src="{avatar_url}" width="{avatar_image_width}" height="{avatar_image_height}" class="avatar" alt="{author}'s avatar" /> {/if} 
                <div class="comment-meta">
                  <h5 class="author">By: {name} On: {comment_date format="%Y %m %d"} <a href="#" class="comment-reply-link">Reply</a></h5>
                </div>
                <!-- end .comment-meta -->

                <div class="comment-body">
                  <p>{comment}</p>
                </div>
                <!-- end .comment-body --> 
              </article>         
            </li>
{/exp:comment:entries}
          </ol>
        </section>
        <section id="respond">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 blogleft contact">
{exp:comment:form channel="article_wistia_video"} 
              <h3 class="contactTitle">Leave a Comment</h3>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 form-group form-row">
                  <input type="text" class="normal" id="name" placeholder="Name" name="name" value="{name}">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 form-group form-row">
                  <input type="email" class="normal" id="email" placeholder="Email Address" name="email" value="{email}">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 form-group form-row">
                  <textarea name="comment" placeholder="Comment" rows="4" class="normal">{comment}</textarea>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!--<div class="row">
                <label><input type="checkbox" name="save_info" value="yes" {save_info} /> Remember my personal information</label><br />
                <label><input type="checkbox" name="notify_me" value="yes" {notify_me} /> Notify me of follow-up comments?</label><br />
        {if captcha}
                <label for="captcha">Please enter the word you see in the image below:</label><br />
                <p>{captcha}<br />
                <input type="text" name="captcha" value="{captcha_word}" maxlength="20" /></p>
        {/if}
              </div> -->             
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                  <input type="submit" id="submit" name="sumbit" value="Submit" class="button">
                </div>
              </div>
{/exp:comment:form}
          </div>
          </section>
          </article>
        </div>
      </div>`
```

Comment: Hi there! Please describe the error in more detail. What kind of error is it? What is the error text? A screenshot of the error message can also be informative.

Comment: Oh, I see the error is described in the subject. I must admit that for me it never registers (be it forum posts, emails, etc) when the key information only exists in the subject/title. Others might do fine with that, but I'd still recommend adding the error message itself to the body of your question.

Comment: Hey Alex...thank you so much for your time and expertise.

Comment: No problem. Let me know if my answer didn't do the trick and I'll try to make another suggestion. If my answer solved the problem for you please accept it. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) in the help center.

Comment: Based on your reply, I tried to edit the member group settings for Super Admin and just allows me to edit the Name, Description and Member Lists. SO I created a new user group and setup the variables as per above, logged in and then when submitting a comment I get a blank screen...I tried the same "not logged in from another browser... Same: no error, no page load to redirect...now I get the following php notices when logging into SUper Admin Notice
Undefined offset: 0
ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Controller/Members/Members.php, line 702 show details

Comment: If one goes here: http://www.stevenseppinni.com/index.php/site/article_detail_video/this-is-a-video-example                                 you can see the blank to redirect issue now that I am experiencing...kinda loosing faith with EE3, I was trying it out before committing to a large project on the platform...might be going back to EE 2.x

Comment: Yeah, not sure what's causing that 500 error for you. :/

Comment: ya, wasn't giving me that before the tweaks...super strange

Answer (score 1):

One likely possibility to check first:

Make sure the Guests member group (which is essentially any non-logged-in users) have permission to post comments.

In EE2 you'd go to ***Admin > Member Groups > Guests***
and look for **Comment Posting Privileges**

Not positive, but in EE3 I believe this member group setting is called **Submit Comments**
https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/cp/members/groups/form.html#submit-comments